# Javascript get information from one array based on other array. (maybe merge could also work)

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

developers, hackers and watchers :)

I have kinda a issue I can't get my head around the part where I need to pull data from one array based on first array.

Maybe merge them ? does it help

So I have two arrays:

```js
var teams = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue"];
var scores = [4, 45, 21, 34, 76, 56];

var scoreRed = [];
var scoreBlue = [];

var i;
var scoreBlueIndex;
for (i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
  scoreBlueIndex = teams.indexOf("blue");
  scoreBlue = scores[scoreBlueIndex];
}

var ii;
var scoreRedIndex;
for (ii = 0; ii < teams.length; ii++){
  scoreRedIndex = teams.indexOf("red");
  scoreRed = scores[scoreRedIndex];
}


console.log(scoreRed);
console.log(scoreBlue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: the for loop are of no use, you can remove them

Comment: `Maybe merge them ? does it help`  Maybe!!!!,. you should know what you want more than us.  An example output, won't hurt.

Comment: Don't I need them to loop each team and score ?

Comment: @jmargolisvt the question is how can I calculate scores for each teams.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are scoreRed and scoreBlue are scalar variables but you had declared them as arrays. See the following working snippet.

```js
var teams = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue"];
var scores = [4, 45, 21, 34, 76, 56];

var scoreRed=0;
var scoreBlue=0;

var i;
var scoreBlueIndex;
for (i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
  scoreBlueIndex = teams.indexOf("blue", i);
  if(scoreBlueIndex > -1) {
    scoreBlue = scoreBlue + scores[scoreBlueIndex];
    i=scoreBlueIndex;
   }
   else break;
}

var ii;
var scoreRedIndex;
for (ii = 0; ii < teams.length; ii++){
  scoreRedIndex = teams.indexOf("red", ii);
  if(scoreRedIndex > -1) {
     scoreRed = scoreRed + scores[scoreRedIndex];
     ii=scoreRedIndex;
  }
  else break;
}


console.log(scoreRed);
console.log(scoreBlue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I updated my code, I was trying to get all team corresponding scores in array. (I know how to count array elements) but still struggle to crack this one

Comment: @Mer0 But you have 4 reds and 2 blues. Do you want to sum of the scores for blue and red each? Or do you want to print each one individually - total of 7?

Comment: Yes that's my problem I want to sum scores for blue and read team each.

I'm was writing double for loop but failed, that's why I try with two for loops.

Comment: @Mer0, aah that part was not clear in your question. Now since you have clarified it, see my updated answer. Let me know if it still doesn't solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Using an object literal, and Array.reduce, you can do something like ->

```js
var teams = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue"];
var scores = [4, 45, 21, 34, 76, 56];

var results = teams.reduce((a,c,i) => {
  return (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + scores[i]) && a;
}, {});

console.log(`Red: ${results.red}`);
console.log(`Blue: ${results.blue}`);
```

`return (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + scores[i]) && a;`

The above code may look a little cryptic, but ti's not hard once you get used to them.  Firstly, the parameters that are sent to this `a,c,i`  These are the values sent from the reduce function, and they stand for `accumulator`, `currentValue` and the `currentIndex`..  More details on reduce here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a

`a[c] =`, This is where we are setting the object literal, `c` will either equal `blue` or `red`, so it would expand to `a["red"] =` or `a["blue"] =`

`a[c] || 0` because we are storing inside an object literal it might not yet exists, so this just sets the value to 0..

Finally we just add the current score using `i` that is the index value of the array, to get the score.  `score[i]`..

The `&& a` bit at the end -> 
When using reduce you normally return the `accumulator` , so the `(formula) && a` means it will always return `a`.  It's just a shorthand so you don't have to use another line `return a`.

Comment: Yes, I can use it to sum all values in array, but I kinda don't understand Your example, that return part does it helps to sort by teams ?

Comment: Instead of an array, it uses an object literal to group the reds & the blues..  The return bit I'll update answer on why it all means.

Comment: thank You for explaining this ! Still unclear to be honest but I will dig around and learn.